# Android - Unfortunately app has stopped - Google maps

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a problem with my app.
Everything is okay, but when I try to add fragment of map to my activity, my app has stopped. I think everything is okay: i have my own Api key from Google, permissions and etc. In my code i pointed what's new in my code.

```
public class OpisMiejscaActivity extends FragmentActivity 
{

    Miejsce zMiejsce;
    boolean mShowMap;
    GoogleMap zMap;
    private ImageView imgView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.opis_miejsca_activity);

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        //this line is new      
        mShowMap = GooglePlayServiceUtility.isPlayServiceAvailable(this) &&   initMap();

        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        zMiejsce = b.getParcelable(".model.Miejsce");

        display();

    }

    //this initMap is new
    private boolean initMap() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(zMap == null)
        {
            MapFragment mapFrag = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            zMap = mapFrag.getMap(); 
        }
        return (zMap != null);
    }

    private void display() 
    {

        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.titleText);
        tv.setText(zMiejsce.getTytul1());


        NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.priceText);
        tv.setText(nf.format(zMiejsce.getKoszt()));

        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.descText);
        tv.setText(zMiejsce.getOpis());


        //this if is new
        if (mShowMap)
        {
            CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(zMiejsce.getLatLng(), 5);
            zMap.moveCamera(update);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.opis_miejsca, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_goto_action :
            break;
        case android.R.id.home:
            break;
        }
        return false;
    }



}
```

Activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/Fragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        class="com.example.mysteriouspoland.OpisMiejscaActivityF" />

    <!-- display map with map fragment -->

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_weight="1" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mysteriouspoland"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.mysteriouspoland.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.mysteriouspoland.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.mysteriouspoland.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".DetailActivity"/>
        <activity android:name=".GPSLicenseActivity"/>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="myapikeyfromgoogle" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Log:

```
12-16 21:06:37.760: D/AndroidRuntime(586): Shutting down VM
12-16 21:06:37.760: W/dalvikvm(586): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x413582a0)
12-16 21:06:37.875: E/AndroidRuntime(586): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-16 21:06:37.875: E/AndroidRuntime(586): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.mysteriouspoland/com.example.mysteriouspoland.OpisMiejscaActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
12-16 21:06:37.875: E/AndroidRuntime(586):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1545)
12-16 21:06:37.875: E/AndroidRuntime(586):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1420)
12-16 21:06:37.875: E/AndroidRuntime(586):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3446)
12-16 21:06:37.875: E/AndroidRuntime(586):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3407)
12-16 21:06:37.875: E/AndroidRuntime(586):  at com.example.mysteriouspoland.MainActivity.onListItemClick(MainActivity.java:142)
12-16 21:06:37.875: E/AndroidRuntime(586):  at android.app.ListActivity$2.onItemClick(ListActivity.java:319)
12-16 21:06:37.875: E/AndroidRuntime(586):  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:301)
12-16 21:06:37.875: E/AndroidRuntime(586):  at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1276)
12-16 21:06:37.875: E/AndroidRuntime(586):  at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3067)
12-16 21:06:37.875: E/AndroidRuntime(586):  at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3963)
12-16 21:06:37.875: E/AndroidRuntime(586):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
12-16 21:06:37.875: E/AndroidRuntime(586):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-16 21:06:37.875: E/AndroidRuntime(586):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-16 21:06:37.875: E/AndroidRuntime(586):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
12-16 21:06:37.875: E/AndroidRuntime(586):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-16 21:06:37.875: E/AndroidRuntime(586):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-16 21:06:37.875: E/AndroidRuntime(586):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
12-16 21:06:37.875: E/AndroidRuntime(586):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
12-16 21:06:37.875: E/AndroidRuntime(586):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

After add OpisMiejscaActivity to Manifest, log:

```
12-16 21:28:05.320: D/AndroidRuntime(7339): Shutting down VM
12-16 21:28:05.320: W/dalvikvm(7339): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x413582a0)
12-16 21:28:05.365: E/AndroidRuntime(7339): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-16 21:28:05.365: E/AndroidRuntime(7339): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mysteriouspoland/com.example.mysteriouspoland.OpisMiejscaActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class fragment
12-16 21:28:05.365: E/AndroidRuntime(7339):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2100)
12-16 21:28:05.365: E/AndroidRuntime(7339):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
12-16 21:28:05.365: E/AndroidRuntime(7339):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
12-16 21:28:05.365: E/AndroidRuntime(7339):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
12-16 21:28:05.365: E/AndroidRuntime(7339):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-16 21:28:05.365: E/AndroidRuntime(7339):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-16 21:28:05.365: E/AndroidRuntime(7339):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
12-16 21:28:05.365: E/AndroidRuntime(7339):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-16 21:28:05.365: E/AndroidRuntime(7339):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-16 21:28:05.365: E/AndroidRuntime(7339):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
12-16 21:28:05.365: E/AndroidRuntime(7339):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
12-16 21:28:05.365: E/AndroidRuntime(7339):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-16 21:28:05.365: E/AndroidRuntime(7339): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class fragment
12-16 21:28:05.365: E/AndroidRuntime(7339):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
12-16 21:28:05.365: E/AndroidRuntime(7339):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
12-16 21:28:05.365: E/AndroidRuntime(7339):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
12-16 21:28:05.365: E/AndroidRuntime(7339):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
12-16 21:28:05.365: E/AndroidRuntime(7339):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
12-16 21:28:05.365: E/AndroidRuntime(7339):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:308)
12-16 21:28:05.365: E/AndroidRuntime(7339):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1924)
12-16 21:28:05.365: E/AndroidRuntime(7339):     at com.example.mysteriouspoland.OpisMiejscaActivity.onCreate(OpisMiejscaActivity.java:46)
12-16 21:28:05.365: E/AndroidRuntime(7339):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
12-16 21:28:05.365: E/AndroidRuntime(7339):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1083)
12-16 21:28:05.365: E/AndroidRuntime(7339):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
12-16 21:28:05.365: E/AndroidRuntime(7339):     ... 11 more
12-16 21:28:05.365: E/AndroidRuntime(7339): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 4030500 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
12-16 21:28:05.365: E/AndroidRuntime(7339):     at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.n(Unknown Source)
12-16 21:28:05.365: E/AndroidRuntime(7339):     at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
12-16 21:28:05.365: E/AndroidRuntime(7339):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.q.v(Unknown Source)
12-16 21:28:05.365: E/AndroidRuntime(7339):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.q.u(Unknown Source)
12-16 21:28:05.365: E/AndroidRuntime(7339):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(Unknown Source)
12-16 21:28:05.365: E/AndroidRuntime(7339):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$b.cE(Unknown Source)
12-16 21:28:05.365: E/AndroidRuntime(7339):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$b.a(Unknown Source)
12-16 21:28:05.365: E/AndroidRuntime(7339):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
12-16 21:28:05.365: E/AndroidRuntime(7339):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onInflate(Unknown Source)
12-16 21:28:05.365: E/AndroidRuntime(7339):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
12-16 21:28:05.365: E/AndroidRuntime(7339):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:290)
12-16 21:28:05.365: E/AndroidRuntime(7339):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)
12-16 21:28:05.365: E/AndroidRuntime(7339):     ... 21 more
12-16 21:28:05.390: D/dalvikvm(7339): GC_CONCURRENT freed 309K, 6% free 13573K/14407K, paused 16ms+13ms, total 51ms
```

Answer (score 0):

you did not declare `OpisMiejscaActivity` as an activity in your manifest

Answer (score 0):

As your received error states:

> You must have the following declaration within the application element:

```
<meta-data    
<android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"   android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

So add this meta-data tag to your xml manifest file:

```
 <meta-data 
         android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
         android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Your exception saying that:

> ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.mysteriouspoland/com.example.mysteriouspoland.OpisMiejscaActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

So here you need to mention your activity in application tag of your manifest file like:

```
<activity android:name="com.example.mysteriouspoland.OpisMiejscaActivity" />
```

and add this meta-data tag to your xml manifest file like:

```
<meta-data 
         android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
         android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```